# Currency symbol conflicting price validation field

Tags: php

I put USD so as to get it before every price (numbers)

```
 $Product_Price="USD".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_price']);
```

Now i validated it as

```
if(!is_numeric($Product_Price))
        {
            $Errormessage[]="Price must be in numbers";
        }
```

Its running the if statement.
How can i get USD with every price but for the user it should be restricted that he can add only numbers.

Comment: If you need to track currency in your database, you probably should do it as a separate field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the value to see if it's numeric before you add the "USD" prefix.

Like this...

```
if(is_numeric($Product_Price))
{
    $Product_Price="USD".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_price']);
}
else
{
    $Errormessage[]="Price must be in numbers";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_price']);
$currency = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_currency']);

if (is_numeric($price))
{
  // insert price and currency in separate columns
}
else
{
  // error message
}
```